# Prove that a function is not a kernel

Tags: kernel-trick, kernel-smoothing

$k(x,x') = \alpha k_1(x,x) + \beta k_2(x',x')$ is a kernel if $k_1$ and $k_2$ are kernels

Prove that this statement is false for all $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}$

How to check for symmetricity of $k(x,x') = k(x',x) $ here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A kernel should be symmetric. Since $k(x,y)\neq k(y,x)$ in general, the statement is not true for any $\alpha, \beta$. The following equality should hold for them to be equal:

$$\alpha(k_1(x,x)-k_1(y,y))=\beta(k_2(x,x)-k_2(y,y))$$

For any given fixed $\alpha,\beta$ (consider non-zero case, since one of them being equal to zero is a trivial case to prove inequality), the ratio $\alpha/\beta$ should be fixed. But, this ratio equals to
$$\frac{\alpha}{\beta}=\frac{k_2(x,x)-k_2(y,y)}{k_1(x,x)-k_1(y,y)}$$

And, it should hold for all $x,y$ pairs. But it can't. So, there is no $\alpha,\beta$ pair satisfying the symmetry condition.

Comment: can you add more details about the symmetricity that why it doesn't hold?

Comment: @christopher I've added my explanation.